# PHP Regex string matching

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to PHP and generally regular expressions. I have to match words that contains strings like `word[0-9]* = any string here` . How do I write a regex for this. So far I have come up with this but it doesnt seem to find the strings properly.

```
$regexp = "word[0-9]* = [A-Z](.*)[a-z]";
```

How would I correct the above expression?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you mean `word[0-9]*` and not for example `word[0-9]+`?  Could you describe what you? Currently you are only describing your (incorrect) solution. You haven't told us what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word[\d]* = (.*)
```

That?

```
preg_match('/word[\d]* = (.*)/', $string, $matches);
```

This is assuming you want to capture the string after the '='.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your way of matching "any string here". Instead you could try this:

```
^word[0-9]+ = .*$
```

In PHP you also need to add delimiters:

```
"/^word[0-9]+ = .*$/"
```

Comment: Hi Thank you. I just had to escape the negation and it works perfectly.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I'm getting an array which is populated with all these matches followed by the rest of the page contents ( I'm trying to parse a html page ). Is there any way I can get only the array of words ?